# Hide the 12 columns of a table before an specific td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the 12 columns before the TOTALSALARY td with some button and with the same button, show if is hidden, but until now not works, I've trying something like this.

```
$( "input#flt14_BD2015" ).click(function() {
$('td:nth-child(3)').hide();
});
```

Maybe this helps:
In the top of every td exist an input(12):

input#flt2_BD2015, input#flt3_BD2015, input#flt4_BD2015, input#flt5_BD2015, input#flt6_BD2015, input#flt7_BD2015, input#flt8_BD2015, input#flt9_BD2015, input#flt10_BD2015, input#flt11_BD2015, input#flt12_BD2015, input#flt13_BD2015

"Hide the column where is input#flt9_BD2015,input#flt10_BD2015, etc..."

I mean from this:

[image]

To This :

[image]

I hope you can help me, thanks

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fu8b3ryh

Comment: Can you provide the actual html and even better create a code snippet?

Comment: It will be better, if you can provide a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this

```
$( "#DB2015" ).on('click','#hideMonth',function(){
  $('.meses').toggle();
});
```

#hideMonth is a button

```
<button id="hideMonth">Hide</button>
```

You can replace the button for any tag
you can see it working here http://fiddle.jshell.net/fu8b3ryh/1/

I hope I've helped

Comment: Works fine but dont hide the first td. Can you please help me?

Comment: you can add class '.meses' to any tag want to hide

Comment: I just add this `$('#flt9_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();` because the input is the td.